# yubikey/gpg-agent always asking for my PIN when running git commit

Tags: macos, gnupg, gpg-agent, yubikey

recently, git has been asking me for my yubikey pin every 3 or 4 times after i've already typed in my pin. this didn't use to happen before. i'm thinking maybe the card isn't getting read correctly or is getting disconnected somehow. it's become pretty annoying.

~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf:

```
enable-ssh-support
default-cache-ttl 43200
max-cache-ttl 86400
default-cache-ttl-ssh 43200
max-cache-ttl-ssh 86400
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-tty
```

~/.gitconfig:

```
[user]
    signingkey = xxxxxxxxxx
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
```

Answer (score 2):

You likely have the "force signature" flag set on the card. Try `gpg --card-status`:

```
$ gpg --card-status
# snip
Signature PIN ....: forced
```

If you see `Signature PIN ....: forced`, that's your problem. You can change this setting with `gpg --card-edit`:

```
$ gpg --card-edit
> admin
> forcesig
# enter your admin PIN
```

Afterwords, `--card-status` should show `Signature PIN ....: not forced`, and you'll only be asked for your user PIN once per insertion of the Yubikey.